Why is it a type alias and interface not allowed as generic?
here is my util func  and interface
interface I_SeoulAPI {
  AREA: string; //부지 면적
  GUIDANCE: string; // 안내도
  G_LATITUDE: string; // Y좌표(GRS80TM)
  G_LONGITUDE: string; //X좌표(GRS80TM)
  LATITUDE: string; // Y좌표(WGS84)
  LONGITUDE: string; //X좌표(WGS84)
  MAIN_EQUIP: string; // 주요시설
  MAIN_PLANTS: string; // 주요식물
  OPEN_DT: string; // 개원일
  P_ADDR: string; // 주소
  P_ADMINTEL: string; //전화번호
  P_IDX: string; // 연번(공원번호)
  P_IMG: string; // 이미지
  P_LIST_CONTENT: string; // 공원개요
  P_NAME: string; // 관리부서
  P_PARK: string; // 공원명
  P_ZONE: string; // 지역
  TEMPLATE_URL: string; // 홈페이지 바로가기 url
  USE_REFER: string; // 이용시 참고사항
  VISIT_ROAD: string; // 오시는길
}

export function formattedGroupByKey<T extends { [key: string | number]: unknown }>(array: T[], key: keyof T) {
  return array.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    const stringkey = cur[key] as string;
    if (acc.get(stringkey)) {
      acc.get(stringkey)?.push(cur);
    } else {
      acc.set(stringkey, [cur]);
    }
    return acc;
  }, new Map<keyof T, T[]>());
}

and when use those in my page
export const getStaticProps = (async () => {
  const results = await searchSeoulParkInfo('SearchParkInfoService/1/135/');
  const data: I_SearchParkInfoService = results.data;

  return { props: { seoulParkInfo: data.SearchParkInfoService.row } };
}) satisfies GetStaticProps<{
  seoulParkInfo: I_SeoulParkAPI[];
}>;
const MapPage = ({ seoulParkInfo }: { seoulParkInfo: I_SeoulParkAPI[] }) => {
  console.log(seoulParkInfo);
  // 데이터를 해시맵으로 정형화 함
  const formattedData = formattedGroupByKey<I_SeoulParkAPI>(seoulParkInfo, '');

there is something wrong
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/nSTEq0uP.png)
I've solved it.
Type aliases enable type inference.
However, I would like to know the reason why.
export type I_SeoulParkAPI = {
  AREA: string; //부지 면적
  GUIDANCE: string; // 안내도
  G_LATITUDE: string; // Y좌표(GRS80TM)
  G_LONGITUDE: string; //X좌표(GRS80TM)
  LATITUDE: string; // Y좌표(WGS84)
  LONGITUDE: string; //X좌표(WGS84)
  MAIN_EQUIP: string; // 주요시설
  MAIN_PLANTS: string; // 주요식물
  OPEN_DT: string; // 개원일
  P_ADDR: string; // 주소
  P_ADMINTEL: string; //전화번호
  P_IDX: string; // 연번(공원번호)
  P_IMG: string; // 이미지
  P_LIST_CONTENT: string; // 공원개요
  P_NAME: string; // 관리부서
  P_PARK: string; // 공원명
  P_ZONE: string; // 지역
  TEMPLATE_URL: string; // 홈페이지 바로가기 url
  USE_REFER: string; // 이용시 참고사항
  VISIT_ROAD: string; // 오시는길
};

Why not interface but type alias

For future reference: screenshots of IDEs are unfortunately not appropriate here. Please replace images of code/logs/errors/tooltips with plaintext versions.
